# Есть ли слово "ласкаяся"?

Tags: словообразование, грамматика

Есть ли в русском языке слово "ласкаяся"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ласкаясь.

Общее правило: Если перед постфиксом гласная, то пишем СЬ, если перед постфиксом согласная, то СЯ.

В то же время в старых текстах (18 век) можно встретить форму СЯ:

"Тогда Прелепа, ласкаяся к Силославу, раскрыла платье на его груди и, увидя на нём повешенный золотой досканец, спрашивала у него, что бы это такое на нём было. [М. Д. Чулков.  (1766-1768)]

Comment: А сейчас есть такие деепричастия, где после согласной "ся", а не "шись"? Не могу почему-то придумать.

Answer (score 1):

Есть деепричастие "ласкаясь". Его полная форма "ласкаяся".

*"Я еду теперь в Петербург просить о издании ее в свет, ласкаяся, яко нежный отец своего дитяти..."*
Радищев.

В современном языке большинство полных форм на "-ся", перед которым идет гласный, считаются устаревшими (с начала XIX века) и просто старыми, используются стянутые формы.

Тем не менее, многие устаревшие формы встречаются в стилизованных и поэтических текстах.

*Над морем красавица-дева сидит;

И, к другу ласкаяся, так говорит:*
(Лермонтов, "Баллада")

Обратите внимание, что в современных текстах возможно только *"ласкаясь" (ласкаяся) - "К кому?"*  (как у Лермонтова). Раньше нормальным считалось управление родительным падежом (как у Радищева) и ласкаясь чем (*"ласкаясь надеждою" = теша себя надеждою*), это связано с изменением самого значения глагола "ласкаться", от которого образовано деепричастия.

Точности ради следует сказать, что и нестянутую форму как единственную возможную отдельные архаичные деепричастия с гласной перед постфиксом сохранили, в основном по фонетическим причинам, во фразеологизмах (*"[ничтоже] смяшеся"*).